# ggplot with aes_string and mean()

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, histogram

I have the following function:

```
histograms <- lapply(names(stock_markets[2:ncol(stock_markets)]),
       function(n){
         
ggplot(data = stock_markets, aes_string(x = n)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y =..density..), color = "darkblue", fill = "lightblue") +
  stat_function(
    fun = dnorm,
    args = with(stock_markets, c(mean = mean(stock_markets$`n`), sd = sd(stock_markets$`n`)))) +
  scale_x_continuous(n) +
  ggtitle(paste("Histogram of", n, "with Normal Curve")) +
  xlab(names(n) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  
})
```

which basically plots the histograms from the dataframe `stock_markets`. Each column contains a stock price. My issue is that I used `aes_string` to get the names of the columns so that I could use them in `aes` but I can't figure out how to use the `mean()` and `sd()` functions with the `n` argument (which is the column I need) so that I can superimpose the normal distribution on the histogram.

I have tried:

`mean(n)`
`mean(stock_markets[n])`
`` mean(stock_markets$`n`) ``
`mean(stock_markets$"n")`

but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need `stock_markets[[n]]`

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I tried everything except that :).

Comment: data.frame are lists in R. The just have a few extra properties as well. I suppose you could have done `stock_markets[, n]` as well which does not work on lists.

Comment: Got it. Thank you